# mod_rewrite, can't rewrite existing file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to pass all images in a directory to watermark.php using mod_rewrite in .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule \.jpg$ /watermark.php?path=%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L]
```

It works fine on local machine, but on my online production server (shared hosting) all image files are served without rewriting.

mod_rewrite is enabled online, but it ignores the rule if file exists.

What could be wrong?

**UPDATE**

Here's my full setup: there's a domain with a subdomain in a subfolder of main domain's document_root.

```
public_html (example.com DOCUMENT_ROOT)/
    img (img.example.com DOCUMENT_ROOT)/
```

.htaccess in public_html folder:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(inc\.php|log)$">
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
php_value short_open_tag 0

php_value auto_prepend_file /home/username/public_html/bootstrap.inc.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ shop/$1 [L]
```

.htaccess in `img` folder:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(inc|log)$">
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

php_value short_open_tag 0
php_value auto_prepend_file none

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule \.jpg$ /watermark.php?path=%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L]
```

The problem is that existing images in `img` folder are not rewrited. Apache just serve them as is. But if, for example, I request non-existing file the rule works and `echo $_GET['path']` prints the full filepath to non-existing file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(media|image|images)(/?)(.*)$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-_\.]+)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ /watermark.php?path=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The first `RewriteRule` is set to make sure people don't go to that folder - it gives a 403 permission denied (this is optional)

The second one will redirect any images that match letters, numbers, dash, underscore and dot with the extension: jpg, jpeg, png and gif to your watermark.php file. eg:

http://www.domain.com/logo.jpg => path = /logo.jpg

UPDATE:

Since the rule is in a different folder and the root directory of IMG is `/home/username/public_html/img/` the watermark.php file does not exists. Either copy the file you need (watermark.php and its libraries) to the IMG folder or create symblink.

```
cd /home/username/public_html/img/
ln -s ../watermark.php (and other library files as well)
```

Comment: I tried it, but still: request for nonexistent file is rewrited to watermark.php just fine, but if existing file is requested - it's served as is, ignoring watermark.php:(

Comment: @sevenWonders Do you have any other rewrite rules except this one? If yes -- please show ALL of them.

Comment: In addition of other rules (see lazyone comment) what do you see if you echo $_GET['path'] in your watermark.php?

Comment: So example.com document root is the same as img.example.com document root?

Comment: document_root of example.com is `/home/username/public_html/`, and document_root of img.exapmle.com is `/home/username/public_html/img/`

Comment: The `watermark.php` is already in `/home/username/public_html/img/`

Comment: Can you show me the code on watermark? Here's mine and it's working fine: http://pastebin.com/LPQavXGR

Comment: Now my watermark.php looks like this:) - `$path = isset($_GET['path']) ? $_GET['path'] : ''; echo $path;` And it just doesn't get there. I suppose something is wrong with subdomains configuration on shared hosting (cause on my local machine everything works just fine). May be I'll try to rewrite the whole thing without subdomains.

Comment: I would say YES, double check your subdomain config because I copy and paste this code to mine and it works (I can show it to you if you want) - OR - try to put BOTH subdomain and domain at the same level. EG: www.domain.com = /home/user/domain.com/public_html/ and sub.domain.com => /home/user/domain.com/sub_public_html/

Answer (score 0):

htaccess change :

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
```

by

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

This behaviour steel exists on Apache 2.4..

Comment: Are you sure this is the solution to the original problem?

Comment: Yes, i had exactly the same one