# Mod_rewrite mangles URL for preexisting directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've used `mod_rewrite` for years but never encountered this behavior before, and it's had me scratching my head for about two hours now.

Given a website directory structure like this:

```
www/
 +-- .htaccess
 +-- image.py
 +-- images/
       +-- somefolder/
       |    +-- somefile.png
       +-- otherfolder/
            +-- otherfile.png
```

And an .htaccess file that contains just this much:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^images/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ image.py?name=$1 [L,NC]
```

If I request a file or folder that matches the rewrite rule but *doesn't* exist, I get the rewrite as I expect:

```
http://example.com/images/foo          --> http://example.com/image.py?name=foo
http://example.com/images/other-folder --> http://example.com/image.py?name=other-folder
```

But if the file or folder *does* exist, I get really bizarre results:  I'd expect that either the rule applies or it doesn't, but instead of "no change" or "rewrite," I get a really bizarre partially-rewritten URL:

```
http://example.com/images/somefolder   --> http://example.com/somefolder?name=somefolder

> GET /images/somefolder HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.1
> Accept: */*
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Sat, 10 Feb 2018 22:39:29 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< Location: https://www.example.com/images/somefolder/?name=somefolder
```

No other `.htaccess` files exist, so I'm at a loss to explain why a one-liner is producing such weird results.

Disabling `Option -Multiviews` (as suggested here: [mod_rewrite doesnt work if file with same name as argument exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383889/mod-rewrite-doesnt-work-if-file-with-same-name-as-argument-exists) ) has no effect.  The problem seems similar to the one suggested here ( [mod_rewrite, can't rewrite existing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581082/mod-rewrite-cant-rewrite-existing-file) ), but I already have the rule marked as `[L]`.

So does anyone know why this is happening?  Is this a bug?  Is there a way to tell Apache to ignore "real" directories and just apply the rewrite rule?  Or do I have no choice but to redesign my site to avoid this bug/quirk?

(Also, this is a shared host, so I don't even have *read* access to `httpd.conf`, much less the ability to change it, if something in there is causing this.  My hosting company claims it's running Apache 2.2.22, but I can't know for sure.)

Comment: For the record, given how quirky Apache can be, it was less headachey to redesign the app itself around the problem than to try to fix it:  I did so, and have moved on.  But if anybody has a good answer, I'd still love to introduce the right rule to fix this weirdness.

Comment: To confirm your Apache version, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166607/how-do-i-find-the-version-of-apache-running-without-access-to-the-command-line.  But I am stumped, I see nothing wrong in your .htaccess rule...